# How to set background image to every component in angular

Tags: css, angular

I have navbar
and I wrote the navbar in src/app.component.html
I am using router-link for the page to swap components

for every component I have a different background
if I am using background-image for a component it will not display in the whole page
only in the router-link that is under the navbar

what is the best method to do it?

I thought maybe I should an empty div and set it to display absolute and make the background-image width and height for fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

Basic Solution:

1. Create an `app.service`
2. Create a `BehaviourSubject` in the service with the default bg image path as initial.
3. Subscribe to that `BehaviorSubject` value in the `app.component` and set the `background-image` path from this value, you can use the `ngStyle` directive for this.
4. `ngOnInit` of every single navigation component, fire its own bg image path via `BehaviorSubject` from the `app.service`.

[Working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j9zhpn?file=src/app/app.component.html)